# Computing the union and intersection of two unsorted arrays in O(nlogm) time

Tags: algorithm, set, time-complexity, array-algorithms

need help to solve this problem with algorithm ...
Given are two sets A and B with m and n elements, respectively, from a linear order. These sets are not necessarily sorted. Also assume that m ≤ n. Show how to compute A∪B and A ∩ B in O(nlogm) time.

Comment: Actually you could do better than `O(n * log m)` with a HashMap.

Comment: @vivek_23 or worse depending upon your strategy of hash key generation. In the worst case, if you have too many collisions, you're running time complexity might drop down to O(n * m).

Comment: @nellex Agreed, but I presume the map functionality provided by the language would have implemented strong hash functions to reduce the collisions.

Answer (score 3):

As vivek_23 said, you can do better using a hash table with high probability.

However, to achieve *O(n* log *m*), and assuming your sets are stored as arrays, you can sort *A* in *O(m* log *m)* time and then do *n* binary searches for each element of *B* to see if it is also in *A*. Each lookup takes  *O*(log *m)* time, for a total of *O(n* log *m)* time.

So, for *A∪B*, you can copy *A* into a new set *C* in *O(m)* time. Then for each element of B, you do a lookup (binary search) on A. If it's not in A, you add it to C. This way, you'd have spent *O(m + n* log *m)* time to construct *C* and *O(m* log m)* to sort A. Since *m < n*, the total time is *O(n* log *m)* as you'd like.

For *A ∩ B*, you'll start with an empty set *D*. For each element of *B*, you do a lookup in *A*. If it is there, you'll add it to *D*. When you're done, you'll have done *n* lookups on *A*, for a total of *(n* log *m)*.

If you were to insert all the elements of list A into a hash table rather than sorting them, you could do everything in *O(m + n)* time with high probability.

Comment: +1, but re: "you can do better using a hash table with high probability": This only works if you have an appropriate hash function that operates on this element-type. The question doesn't specify that.